# Теги <header> <article> <section> <footer>

Tags: html5

За что отвечает каждый из них?

Какие теги внутри них пишутся?

Можно ли тег <img> прописать внутри?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ответ написан в любом учебнике.

Comment: @Эникейщик, простота вопроса не может быть причиной для закрытия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<header>` задаёт «шапку» сайта или раздела веб-страницы. Внутри «шапки» сайта обычно располагается логотип, название сайта, поисковая форма, навигационные ссылки и др.

нельзя вкладывать внутрь другого `<header>`, а также внутрь элементов `<address>` и `<footer>`. [статья](https://webref.ru/html/header)

---

`<article>` представляет собой независимый фрагмент веб-страницы и, как правило, включает «шапку», основное содержимое и «подвал», в которых располагаются такие части, как заголовок, текст, имя автора, дата публикации, метки, рейтинг статьи и др. `<article>` обычно применяется для статей сайта, сообщений блога и форума, комментариев. [статья](https://webref.ru/html/article)

---

`<section>` задаёт раздел документа, может применяться для блока новостей, контактной информации, глав текста, вкладок в диалоговом окне и др. Раздел обычно содержит заголовок. Допускается вкладывать один элемент `<section>` внутрь другого. [статья](https://webref.ru/html/section)

---

`<footer>` задаёт «подвал» сайта или раздела веб-страницы, в нём может располагаться имя автора, дата документа, контактная и правовая информация.

`<footer>` нельзя вкладывать внутрь другого `<footer>`, а также внутрь элементов `<address>` и `<header>`. [статья](https://webref.ru/html/footer)